# How to insert an element inside a listview without changing the selecteditems

Tags: c#, wpf, list, listview

In WPF, I select multiple items in the listview. In the code-behind, I inserted an element at index 2 using ObservableCollection.SetItem(). The multiple items I selected a while ago will be deselected. How can I insert an element in the listview while not losing the multiple items I selected? 
The code below triggers the deselection of the selected items.

```
this.SetItem(index2, new student("name",age,"school"));
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For one, `SetItem()` does not insert an item, it replaces it. To insert an item use `Insert()`.

As for multi-selection, you're best off implementing a bind-able multi-select `ListView`. One issue with `ListView` is that the `SelectedItems` is not a `DependencyProperty` so it cannot be bound to, and  isn't the most reliable thing to deal with in ViewModels or code.

A good example of how to implement a better `ListView` can be found [Here.](http://grokys.blogspot.com.au/2010/07/mvvm-and-multiple-selection-part-iii.html) There is a 3-part series on binding `ListViews` there which can provide some useful ideas as well.

Comment: I should try this one out. Thanks for the link

Comment: -> is there any other workaround for this problem? The project at its final stage and as much as possible i dont want to re-create the whole collection object?. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of bools for each item in your checklist.

Before inserting new item, check each existing item and see if it is selected and store result in bool list.

Once item is inserted, simply parse back over the bool list and re-set the previously selected items.

Comment: how do you put back the selected items inside the listview? ive tried somethng like listview.selecteditems = list<> but the problem is that the selecteditems property is only read-only. Thanks

Comment: Try myListView.Items[1].Selected = true; or myListBox.SetSelected(index,true);